# Make a custom component by designing in xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-custom-view

After a lot of research, I don't find how to design a custom component in Xml.

I understand that I must create a class that inherits View but in the constructor I would like to reference an xml where I design my object by using some android components.

This is the view content that I put in a chronometer.xml file in the layout folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.fr.loroux.minuteursimple.Chronometer
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customChronometer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00" />

</com.fr.loroux.minuteursimple.Chronometer>
```

But now how can I reference it in by constructor class ?
It's not possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a compound view. To reference your xml layout use the next code in your constructor:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.chronometer, this, true);
```

For more information how to create your view see [Create compound view](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#tutorial_compoundcontrols3).

Comment: Or shorter: `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chronometer, this, true);`

Comment: Or shorter, the last `true` parameter is optional and defaults to false. :)